# NSPersistentCloudKitContainer not syncing data on macOS

Tags: macos, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I am using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` to share data between iOS and macOS app.

I have set up the project according to the [official tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit). And when I made changes from the macOS app, the lastest data will automatically display on my iOS app. But in the other direction when I made changes on iOS, macOS app will not get the lastest version of the data.

I have verified on Cloud Dashboard that the changes made on iOS have been uploaded onto CloudKit server. Just the macOS app and the cloudd process won't create tasks to pull these changes (observed from console.app). And if I quit the macOS app and restart it, lastest data will be pulled.

So the problem is that macOS using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` will not get synced data in the runtime.

One potential reason is that the [official tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit) has mentioned to set the background Remote Notification. I've done this for the iOS app. But for the macOS app, there are no background mode options so I skipped this step.

Any ideas to get the synced data on macOS in time? Thanks very much!